# sort method only sorts first half

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort my Array of "Students" but for some reason, it doesn't sort the students that I add using my addStudent method and only sorts the ones from the text file. Also, the last element in my array gets saved twice and I'm not sure why either, does anybody have any suggestions on how to fix it?

```java
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    
    public class Roster {
        
        private Object [] array = new Student [10];
        private LinkedList <Student> roster = new LinkedList<Student>();
        private int counter = 0;
        
        public Roster (Student student) {// O(1) this runs in constant time
            addStudent(student);
        }
    
        public Student[] getArray() {// O(1) this runs in constant time
            return (Student[]) array;
        }
    
        public void setArray(Student[] array) {// O(1) this runs in constant time
            this.array = array;
        }
    
        public LinkedList<Student> getRoster() { // O(1) this runs in constant time
            return roster;
        }
    
        public void setRoster(LinkedList<Student> roster) {// O(1) this runs in constant time
            this.roster = roster;
        }
        
        public Object[] sort() { //O(n^2) runs n^2 times for the nested for loop
            array = roster.toArray();
            removeNull();
                for(int i =0; i < counter; i++) { // O(n)
                    for(int j =1; j < counter - i; j++) // O(n)
                    if((((Student) array[j - 1]).compareTo((Student) array[j])) >= 1) {
                        Student temp = (Student) array[j-1];
                        array[j-1] = array[j];
                        array[j] = temp;
                }
            }
            return array;
        } 
    
        public void loadRoster() { // O(n) executes the length of the array
            removeNull();
            for(int i =0; i< array.length; i++)
                System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
        
        public void addStudent(Student student) { // O(n) toArray()
            if(counter == 10)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sorry the class is full");
            roster.add(student);
            array = roster.toArray();
            counter++;
            loadRoster();
        }
        
        public void removeStudent(String ID) { // O(n) toArray()
            if(counter <= 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The class is empty");
            roster.remove(IDSearch(ID));            
            array = roster.toArray();
            counter--;
            loadRoster();
        }
        public void removeNull() {
            int k = 0;
            for(int i =0; i < counter; i++) {
                if (array[i] != null)
                    array[k++] = (Student) array[i];
            }   
        }
    
        public Student IDSearch( String IDNumber) {  // O(n) runs the for loop
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length;i++)
                if(((Student) array[i]).getIDNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(IDNumber)) {
                    System.out.print(array[i]);
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                    return (Student) array[i];
                }
            
            System.out.println("Student not found");
            return null;
        }
        
        public Student nameSearch(String lastName , String firstName) { // O(n) for loop for array length
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length;i++)
                if((((Student) array[i]).getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(lastName)) && (((Student) array[i]).getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName))) {
                    System.out.println(array[i]);
                    return (Student) array[i];
                }
            System.out.print("Student not found");
            return null;    
        }
        
        public void save() { // constant time
            removeNull();
            sort();
            loadRoster();
        }
    
        public void saveChanges() throws FileNotFoundException{ // O(n) for loop to print to the new file
            save();
            File file = new File ("Roster.txt");
            
            if (file.exists())
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file);
            for(int i =0; i <array.length; i++)
                out.println(array[i`enter code here`]);
            
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You will have to call sort() after you insert any Student.

Comment: I have a feeling you should take a look at your removeNull method for the double entry of the last student.

Comment: i know this is where its coming from because when I don't call it the names print fine but I'm not sure whats causing it. do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to call your `sort()` method.

Comment: i call it in my main function but I didn't put that up